# Why does my test fail when I use FactoryGirl in this manner?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I'm testing my User model and studying how FactoryGirl works. When I do this in my **user_spec.rb**:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = User.new(username: 'ExampleUser', email: 'user@example.com', timezone: 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)', password: 'example')
end
```

Everything passes, but if I do:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
end
```

It fails the test to see if the user's username and email are taken already.

```
1) User when username is already taken
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
       expected valid? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:151:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

  2) User when email address is already taken
     Failure/Error: it { should_not be_valid }
       expected valid? to return false, got true
     # ./spec/models/user_spec.rb:142:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'

Finished in 1.8 seconds
29 examples, 2 failures
```

These are the test:

```
  describe 'when email address is already taken' do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end

  describe 'when username is already taken' do
    before do
      user_with_same_username = @user.dup
      user_with_same_username.username = @user.username.upcase
      user_with_same_username.save
    end
    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
```

Can someone explain? I thought FactoryGirl was suppose to let me use it like `User.new`, my first example which works.

Comment: Do you reset your DB before each test example with something like database-cleaner (https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`FactoryGirl.create` actually creates the record, whereas `User.new` only instantiates the model but does not actually save the record.

If you want to only instantiate the model, you should use `FactoryGirl.build`:

```
before(:each) do
  @user = FactoryGirl.build(:user)
end
```

See the [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) for details.

So what I think is happening with your current code is that when you create the user with `FactoryGirl.create`, it actually saves the record with no validation issues (since the duplicate has not been created yet). When you save the user with the same email with `user_with_same_email.save`, it does not actually save that user but you don't see that. Then when you check if the original user is valid, it says yes because you already saved it before trying (and failing) to create the duplicate.

Make sense? Anyway just switch to `FactoryGirl.build` and both tests should pass.

Comment: I get what you are saying about create and all, but it doesn't make sense logically.  FactoryGirl.create(:user) should make User.first in his DB, and then blah = @user.dup, he does his thing, and then blah.save! should throw an error.  If not, what good is this Factory Girl? I know I've have this issue like our OP did, and it doesn't make sense to me, and drives me bonkers. I mean in real life, he can do it in console and he'd get an error, so his tests should reflect that, imo.

Comment: Now I understand why I couldn't get some of my other factories working. Thanks OP.

Comment: @pjammer it does make sense. FactoryGirl.create(:user) saves the record with no issues since the duplicate doesn't exist yet. Then the duplicate is saved (but not actually created since validation fails, but that doesn't really matter). Then the original record is checked for validity, and of course it *is* valid since it has already been saved and the duplicate was never created. In a console the same thing would happen.

Comment: @LearningRoR glad to have been of help!

Comment: I don't understand why you are saying THEN the original is checked for validity AFTER it's saved?  I see it as `@user = FG.create; #saves fine. b = @user.dup #duplicates same obj. b.email = @user.email.upcase #changes it but is still the same; b.save!` should throw validation error.  I just tried this in console, but without FG.create, and used my User.first instead.

Comment: @pjammer I think perhaps you're confusing *what* is being checked for validation errors in the specs. In `it { should_not be_valid }` the subject is `@user`, not `user_with_same_email` or `user_with_same_username`. `blah.save!` would throw an error, but he's calling it without the bang, so it doesn't throw the error and just fails to save (silently).

Comment: just to repeat, `b.save!` would throw an error but he's calling `b.save`, which fails silently.

Comment: So his tests are wrong too then?  You are right about my lack of understanding the it line, but wouldn't he want to make sure `user_with_same_username` is not valid?  What good is testing a Factory like that?

Comment: No his tests aren't wrong. You could argue that a bang would be good to have, but that wasn't the problem with the test, the problem was that the subject was being saved, when it should only have been instantiated. Anyway this is well beyond the question posed here, which I have answered.

Comment: I'd argue that your Factories should be your happy path, always saved, and you test against them, but whatever. I just wish I could rip out Rspec and factory girl from my daily life. #stuck.

Answer (score 1):

Generally when testing a field, using Factory Girl, that has `validates_uniqueness_of` it's best to use a [sequence](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md#sequences).

When using a sequence, every time you create a record with `FactoryGirl.create(:user)`, the username will always be unique. This allows you to work with "real" records in your database without having to manually correct for conflicting values.

```
factory :user do
  sequence :username do |n}
    "user_#{n}"
  end
end
```

**Note:** I don't like the idea of testing records that haven't been added to the database. I can't think of any solid reason why it would be a problem. The only problem I can think of is the fact that you won't be able to test associations.

---

Something else that I keep noticing with your questions is you use a `before` block and create instance variables. In RSpec there is a method called `let` will create the variable when it is needed.

This would make your `user_spec.rb` file work like so.

```
describe User do
  let(:user) { create(:user, :first_name => "John", :last_name => "Doe") }

  it "should get full name" do
    user.full_name.should == "John Doe"
  end
end
```

`let` also has a bang method that will create the variable whether it is used in the `it` block or not.